# why is a double pointer being used to create a Queue?

Tags: c++, pointers

I have two classes Node and Queue. In Queue constructor we need to create an array of type Node in the heap. My question is why we should use a double pointer `Node **Q` and then create an array `Q=new Node*[size]` like this when we could have done created an array of Nodes with a single pointer? like `Node *Q` and `Q = new Node[size]`

```
   class Node
    {
    public:
     Node *lchild;
     int data;
     Node *rchild;
    };

class Queue {
private:
 int front;
 int rear;
 int size;
 Node **Q;
public:
 Queue(){front=rear=-1;size=10;Q=new Node*[size];}
 Queue(int size){front=rear=-1;this->size=size;;Q=new
Node*[size];}
 void enqueue(Node *x);
 Node *dequeue();
 int isEmpty(){ return front==rear;}
};
```

Comment: Because this code was written by a Java programmer who doesn't realize that things other than pointers exist.

Comment: Looks like the writer wants their queue to be an array of binary trees. I think you should find a different example to learn from. This person either is solving a very interesting problem or is insane.

Comment: @KenWayneVanderLinde "Don't use `new` ever" is one of those thing I feel it's appropriate to tell a learner of C++, like how we say "Don't use `goto` ever" to students and then we all encounter that 1 in a million situation where `goto` actually makes sense to use.

Comment: There are two ways to go with this (ignoring `vector` and smart pointers for the moment). One is `Q` becomes `int * Q;` and holds an array of `int`. `Q = new int[size];` The other is Node becomes a linked list element, `struct Node { Node * next; int data; };`, and `Q` becomes the head pointer of a linked list. Unless you're required to implement the queue with a linked list, use the array as it is orders of magnitudes simpler.

Comment: @agastyateja Smart pointers (`unique_ptr` or `shared_ptr`, generally) should be used to own memory in the heap, and references (`&`) should be used to borrow data that you don't own. Manually managing memory with `new` is error-prone and old-fashioned, unless you have a very good reason to do it.

Comment: The real problem with `new` is the obligations that entails. If you allocate something you *own* it and you're responsible for releasing that memory with `delete`, as per [RAII rules](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/raii). This can get very tricky and complicated in non-trivial programs. If you avoid `new` and instead use references, cheap copies, pointer wrappers like `std::unique_ptr` and such, it *dramatically* simplifies your code.

Comment: Sorry, I missed the earlier comment directed at me. I cannot fathom a reason why one would make a queue from a tree structure. A queue is a linear data structure. Items go in one side and come out the other. A linked list makes some sense, but the only reason I can think of for using a tree is if you have an ordered queue like a priority queue.

Comment: I'm approaching this from too practical a standpoint, I think. This might make an educational exercise, but I can't help but think there are ways to teach tree structures that you may find a use for in a real program. What you say makes sense, but doesn't explain the need for the array of trees unless they want a queue of trees. If that's the goal then yes, you do need a double pointer. The first indirection gets you to the array of trees. The second indirection gets you to a single tree.

Comment: @user4581301 Array of *nodes*, not necessarily trees. Yes, there is a not-so-uncommon pattern of identifying nodes with trees or subtrees, but that identification only holds if the node has actually been added to a tree structure. Strictly speaking `Node` objects can exist independently.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, let's make it clear that we are looking at two distinct data structure:

1. A binary tree, which is defined by `Node` objects.
2. A queue backed by a fixed-size buffer (possibly it's a ring buffer).

There is also an algorithm that uses these data structures. Based on one of the comments, this algorithm builds a binary tree from the queued nodes. In other words, the algorithm want to modify the original `Node` objects - it doesn't want to modify copies of them.

So the reason to allocate an array of `Node *` is so that the queue doesn't have to copy the `Node` objects. Instead, the pointer that is enqueued is the very same pointer that is later dequeued. This allows the linking algorithm to operate on the original nodes, and therefore to have the desired effect.

Comment: I can't really say since I have no idea what algorithm this is being used for or what kind of binary tree you need :) But at the end of the day, this is educational code (at least I think that's so), so what's important is that you understand what is going on. In the real world, you're not likely to implement your own tree or queue, and you would instead use standard utilities such as [`::std::queue`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/queue) for a FIFO queue, or [`::std::set`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set) which is typically a tree.